# How to install ember-cli 4.12.1

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When I use npm to install ember-cli 4.12.1 by below command

```
#npm install -g ember-cli@4.12.1
```

The install is successful, but I see ember-cli version is 3.27.0

```
#ember --version
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
WARNING: Node v18.16.0 is not tested against Ember CLI on your platform. We recommend that you use the most-recent "Active LTS" version of Node.js. See https://git.io/v7S5n for details.
ember-cli: 3.27.0
node: 18.16.0
os: linux x64
```

The version is available from npm, so how can I install ember-cli 4.12.1?

```
#npm view ember-cli
ember-cli@4.12.1 | MIT | deps: 93 | versions: 315Command line tool for developing ambitious ember.js appshttps://cli.emberjs.com/release/
......
```

I also manually download tarball from https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli/-/ember-cli-4.12.1.tgz and installed the tarball, but the version still is 3.27.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're running (global) `ember` or `npx ember-cli` in a project that already has `ember-cli` installed, it'll defer to the locally installed versioned for that project.

you'll want to change the `ember-cli` version in your projects package.json to upgrade.